# Generic smoothness lemma applied to the Albanese map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a nonsingular irregular complex projective algebraic variety of dimension $n \geq 4$ (i.e $h^1(\mathcal O_X) >0 $). Also assume that $K_X + (n-1)L$ is numerically effective, where $K_X$ is the canonical line bundle and $L$ is a fixed ample line bundle. Consider the Albanese map $\alpha : X \to \text{Alb}(X)$. Then from *generic smoothness lemma* there exists a non-empty open subset $V \subset \text{Alb}(X)$ such that the map $\alpha : \alpha^{-1}(V) \to V$ is smooth. Let's denote a general fiber of $\alpha$ by $F_{\alpha}$, which is the inverse image of an element of $V$ under $ \alpha$.

Then my question is that how the following  true : each such general fiber can be written as $F_{\alpha} = \cup_{i=1}^{r}F_i$, where each $F_i$ is a smooth sub-variety such that for $k \neq l$, $F_k \cap F_l = \emptyset$ and $\text{dim}(F_k) =\text{dim}(F_l)$?

I don't know whether it's true for any generic smoothness case or it's true for only Albanese map.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many issues here. In general, it is possible that $\alpha$ is not onto, and then generic smoothness says nothing, since you might end up with the open set, the complement  of $\alpha(X)$ and fibers are empty.

If $f:X\to Y$ is a dominant map of varieties (over complex numbers, say), generic smoothness says there is a non-empty open set such that the inverse images of points in this set are smooth. Generic flatness says there is a non-empty open set where the map is flat. So, taking the intersection of these open sets, we may assume that the fibers over points in this open set are smooth and all its irreducible components have the same dimension (this is a consequence of flatness). Now as in your notation, write a fiber $F=\cup F_i$, $F_i$ irreducible components. Then, clearly $\dim F_i$ is constant from what I said. I will leave you to show that at any point of $F_i\cap F_j$, $i\neq j$, $F$ is singular. So, these intersections must be empty.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. But Is it known know under what condition on a smooth polarized irregular  projective variety $X$ of $\text{dim}(X) = n$, the corresponding Albanese map $\alpha$ is dominant ? For example for $n=4$ what I mentioned In my question is true. But what about $n >4$?

Comment: @HARRY If $X=E\times\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, then it is an irregular variety of of dimension $n$ for any curve $E$ of positive genus. But, the albanese map is not dominant once genus of $E$ is greater than one.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the   irregular varieties that I am talking about has this property that $K_X+(n-1)L$ is numerically effective, where $K_X$ is the canonical divisor and $L$ is the fixed polarization and $n= \text{dim}(X)$. Does it contribute in some way for $\alpha$ being dominant?

Comment: Let $X$ be a normal projective variety. The surjectivity of the Albanese map holds if $-K_X$ is nef; see Section 3.7 of Debarre's book "Higher-dimensional Algebraic Geometry". Also, if $X$ is special in the sense of Campana, then the Albanese map is surjective (see Theorem 2.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2958) Finally, if $X$ has a dense entire curve, then the Albanese map is also surjective; see Theorem 6.1.

Comment: Now I have edited the question with assumptions on $X$ as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Let $X$ be a curve of genus at least two. Let $L=\omega_X$. Then $K_X + (n-1)L$ is ample for any $n\geq 1$. But the Albanese map is not surjective.

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar, Again I forgot to mention that the variety that I am interested in is of dimension atleast $4$

Comment: Let $X$ be as in my comment above. Now consider $X^n$ for $n\geq 4$.